# Sorting array by right shifting any three elements of the array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of N integers such that 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ N.
(a permutation of N integers).

> ie for array elements can be `5,1,2,3,4.`

I need to sort the array by picking any three indices a[p], a[q], a[r] and do a right shift operation...

What will be the minimum number of operations to sort the array?

For this array `5, 8, 6, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1, 10, 4` answer is `5` and indices to be shifted  are

```
1 5 7;
1 2 8;
3 6 9;
3 4 10;
3 4 10;
```

Comment: For this array 5 8 6 3 7 9 2 1 10 4 answer is 5. and indices are
1 5 7; 
1 2 8; 
3 6 9; 
3 4 10;  
3 4 10;

Comment: Add this information and own thoughts to question to male it more clear.

Comment: This appears to be from a ongoing contest: https://www.codechef.com/MAY20B/problems/TRPLSRT.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

Let's see - we start out with

```
 5 8 6 3 7 9 2 1 10 4
```

Right-rotating one position though offsets 1, 2, 8 (1-based) yields

```
 1 5 6 3 7 9 2 8 10 4
```

So now 1 and 8 are both in their final position

Then, rotating though 4, 9, 10 yields

```
 1 5 6 4 7 9 2 8 3 10
```

Now 1, 4, 8, and 10 are in their final position

Then, rotating though 3, 6, 9 yields

```
 1 5 3 4 7 6 2 8 9 10
```

Now 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, and 10 are in their final position

Finally, rotating though 2, 5, 7 yields

```
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

So 4 rotations.

Now, I did this by hand. Developing the algorithm to find solutions like this one is left as an exercise for the reader ;)